# Find $E[1/X^2]$ using the density of $X$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> A random number $X$ is sampled with the following probability density
>     $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac32x^2(1-x),  & \text{if $x$ is in [-1, 1]} \\
> 0, & \text{else}
> \end{cases}  
> $$
>   We define another random variable by $Y=\frac{1}{X^2}$.
>   Find $E[Y]$ using the density of $X$.

I am not completely sure on how to do this, do I substitute $\frac{1}{X^2}$ into the density of X and find E[Y] with the integral? I know that Y is defined only in (0, 1] and undefined at 0. I calculated the cdf of Y to be:
$$
F(Y) =
\begin{cases}
\pm \sqrt{\frac1Y},  & \text{if $Y$ is in (0, 1]} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}  
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The mean of $Y$, that is, of $\frac{1}{X^2}$, is $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{3}{2}x^2(1-x)\,dx$.  That is the easy way. Alternately, you could find the distribution of $Y$ and then use that to find the mean of $Y$. That is substantially more work. You tried to do that. It was not done correctly. Note that $Y$ takes on all values $\gt 1$.

Comment: I want to learn how to do it both ways, so I would start by finding the possible values of Y, then the cdf, then the pdf, correct? The possible values of Y: Y is in (0,1], and the cdf would be                                    F(Y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y \le 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $y \gt 1$} \\                                                                        \pm \sqrt{\frac1Y}, & \text{if $0 \lt y \le 1$}
\end{cases}

Comment: I have written out an answer, that shows (i) the easy way and (ii) the procedure for finding the cdf of $Y$.

Comment: I see what you did, but is the cdf that I wrote in my previous comment stating the possible values of Y and it's probabilities?

Comment: The proposed cdf is not right. It should be $0$ if $y\lt 1$. For $y\ge 1$  it is substantially more complicated than your suggestion.  The $\pm\sqrt{1/Y}$  cannot be correct, we cannot have a random variable in the expression, and a cdf can never be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to apply the *Law of the Unconscious Statistician* (please see Wikipedia). If $Y=\frac{1}{X^2}$ then
$$E(Y)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{3}{2}x^2(1-x)\,dx.$$

A much harder way, in this case, is to find the distribution of $Y$, and then use the result to find $E(Y)$.

Note that $Y$ takes on values in the interval $[1,\infty)$. We find the cdf $F_Y(y)$. Then we can find the density function $f_Y(y)$, and use that in the usual way to find $E(Y)$. We will only show the calculation of the cdf.  It will not be pleasant!

For $y\ge 1$, we have 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr\left(\frac{1}{X^2}\le y\right)=\Pr\left(X^2\ge \frac{1}{y}\right)=\Pr\left(|X|\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right).$$

It follows that
$$F_Y(y)=1-\Pr\left(|X|\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right)=1-\int_{-1/\sqrt{y}}^{1/\sqrt{y}} \frac{3}{2}x^2(1-x)\,dx$$
for $y\ge 1$.

Now to find $f_Y(y)$ we either integrate, and then differentiate, or differentiate under the intgral sign, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.